# I cannot get populate a user infor in an object with another field

Tags: mongoose, populate

I have a field in user model [user model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pANIM.png). It describes the user is check-in or not in a challenge

When I get the challenge, I want it will show all user's information and the is_checkin field instead of this
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br1jL.png)
Or do you have another best way to organize the database in Mongoose?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.